# Chainging Select Boxes (Country, State, City)

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have 3 select option, Country, State, City.

[image: city]

I have a php page where I would like to select a location from a list of countries, states, and cities. The page contains other data for user signup (name, email, etc) so I don't want to refresh the page or anything when the select boxes refresh. Currently, each of the select boxes just load the full list of countries, states, or cities. I want them to be chained so I don't have duplicate city names (same name in different states or countries).

I want to when select America, List of cities New York bring me.

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="country_id">Country</label>
        <select id="country_id" name="country_id" class="form-control">
            <option></option>
            @foreach($countries as $country)
                <option {{ optional(auth()->user()->country)->id == $country->id ? 'selected' : '' }} value="{{ $country->id }}">
                    {{ $country->name }}
                </option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="state_id">State</label>
        <select id="state_id" name="state_id" class="form-control">

        </select>
        <input type="text" name="state_name" value="{{ auth()->user()->state_name }}" id="state_id" class="form-control d-none">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="city_id">City</label>
        <select id="city_id" name="city_id" class="form-control">

        </select>
        <input type="text" name="city_name" value="{{ auth()->user()->city_name }}" id="city_id" class="form-control d-none">
    </div>
</div>
```

js

```
$(document).on('change', '#country_id', function() {
    let country_id = $(this).val();
    if(country_id == 1){
        $('#city_id').find('#state_id');
    }
    let select = $('#state_id');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '{{ route('findIDCoubtry') }}',
        data: {'id':country_id},
        success: function(data){
            select.html('');
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                select.append('<option value="'+data[i].id+'">'+data[i].name+'</option>');
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log('this is a error');
        },
    });
}).trigger('change');
```

Comment: So, what doesn't work in current jquery code ...? Also that you need to do at your backend code i.e : return only match options to ajax  .

Comment: I want to when select America, List of cities New York bring me.         This has not an error

Comment: The `$('#city_id').find('#state_id');` line is not working

Comment: What do you expect it  to do ? Please elaborate ?

Comment: After selecting the country, I want to take the ID of city number 1 from the database and display it.